# Flatlist scrollToIndex produces whitespace on iOS

Tags: react-native

The design of the application I am working on changes the layout based on the width of the device and there is a `Flatlist` component that calls `scrollToIndex` on the selected item so that it does not fall out side of the view when the app changes it's layout. If the last item is selected and `scrolltToIndex` is called, on iOS it will scroll the item all the way to the top and hide all the items above it. That makes it appear like it is the only item left and the only way to bring back the other items is to manually pull down the list. On android it works perfectly i.e it will only scroll an item high enough to fit as many items below it as possible (if more than height of container, it just scrolls it to the top).

Answer (score 0):

From the [FlatList>ScrollToIndex](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/flatlist.html#scrolltoindex) docs:

> Note: Cannot scroll to locations outside the render window without specifying the getItemLayout prop.

Because FlatList is *virtualized* (i.e. efficient because it doesn't render the full list offscreen), it doesn't know the location of all of the elements (since they're not pre-rendered, and hence their size is unknown).  It needs you to help by providing element sizes through [`getItemLayout`](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/flatlist.html#getitemlayout) to scroll beyond what's near visible. I suspect "near visible" may vary device to device with different memory settings.  If you don't do this, you can end up with gaps in your list since exact placement is unknown.

So, you'll need to implement `getItemLayout` or use the less performant (and depricated) `ListView` component.

Comment: `getItemLayout` is implemented i should clarify. I manage a array on a parent component that doesn't unmount with unique ids of the rendered components. Needed to do that because the items rendered in the Flatlist can vary in height. thanks for your time

Comment: And presumably you're confident you're computing the heights properly?

Comment: yep onLayout callback